# How to save a web page into a HTML file with PowerShell or C#?

Tags: html, powershell, google-chrome

I have the following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052574/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2017) , and when I open the link via Chrome and then right-click the page and then choose "save as" to save the page into a HTML file (c:\temp\cu2.html)

[image]

After it is saved, I can open this cu2.html file with an HTML editor (say VS2015), and I can see
inside the file, there is  tag as seen below

[image]

However, if I open the link with IE11 (instead of Chrome), and then save the same page as HTML file, I cannot find this  tag at all. Actually, the html file saved from IE11 is the same content as what I can extract with PowerShell script below.

```
#Requires -version 4.0
$url = 'https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052574/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2017';

$wr = Invoke-WebRequest $url;
$wr.RawContent.contains('<table') # returns false

$wr.RawContent | out-file -FilePath c:\temp\cu2_ps.html -Force; #same as the file saved from the webpage to html file in IE
```

So my question is:

Why is a web page saved (as html file) in Chrome is different from that in IE?

How can I use PowerShell(or C#) to save such web page into a HTML file (same as the file saved in Chrome)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pages uses AngularJS and also jQuery. It means some contents will be loaded after document ready. So when you send the request using `Invoke-WebRequest`, you only receive the original content of the page. Other contents will be loaded after a while.

To solve the problem, you can automate IE to get expected result. It's enough to wait fr the page to get ready and also wait a bit to run AngularJs logic and download required content, then get content of document element:

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$url = "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052574/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2017"
$ie.silent = $true
$ie.navigate($url)
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
Start-Sleep 10
$ie.Document.documentElement.innerHTML > "C:\Tempfiles\output.html"
$ie.Stop()
$ie.Quit()
```

Comment: It really works ! Thanks Reza. On the other hand (I am demanding a little bit too much, I know.) Is it possible that you can come up with a solution without IE involved so I can use it where there is no IE installed (because in my environment, an IE is not allowed to install on a server). But nevertheless, I vote your solution as an answer and will grant you the bounty points in 20 hrs (as the system does not allow me to grant you the points at this moment). Thanks again for your great help.

Comment: Without a browser, your answer is "No you cannot." because you need a script engine and a DOM engine and so on to execute javascripts and manipulate DOM.

Comment: But if you are going to use a different `Browser` for automation, like Chrome, you can rely on using [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io). I've used it with Windows Forms. Which means you can use it in PowerShell as well. In worst case, you can write a C# program using the CefSharp to do it for you. But, in an environment which IE is not allowed, I believe using CefSharp has lot's of risks to use. I'm not talking about CefSharp, in fact all other 3rd party browsers.

Comment: By the way, I added `$ie.Stop()` and `$ie.Quit()` at the end of the script. It's a really important edit, don't miss it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) and [Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) packages to download and save html content:

```
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options))
{
    driver.Url = "https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052574/cumulative-update-2-for-sql-server-2017";
    File.WriteAllText("cu2_ps.html", driver.PageSource);
}
```

But that means that you need to have chrome installed. You could use IE driver as well, but then probably better to use IE COM automation as was suggested in another answer.

Comment: Andrii, I run your code in Visual Studio 2015 interactive window, and the result is still the same as what I got in my question, i.e. there is no <table> tag at all. At first sight, I really like your solution because it does not need to deal with IE, and so it is very clean and can be used where IE is not installed. But unfortunately, the solution does not work.

Comment: @jyao I have just opened the html it it shows 404 page not found that's why there is no content. I should have checked before posting here. Let me investigate a bit more.

Comment: @jyao, it is true that scripts must run for the content to be rendered. Alternative solution will be to use Selenium webdriver, but probably it is not much different from the suggested approach with IE COM automation. Cheers.